# What is the best apporach to a customizable theming in SPA Architecture

Tags: architecture, web-development, web-applications, software, architectural-patterns

I'm interested in developing single-paged application and there are few question I need to get clarified before moving on. One of them is customizable theming implementations. As for traditional web applications, we could easily customize a page but since SPA is a bit more complex than that, what would be the best approach to handle such a scenario?

For an example say I have developed a single page application and a client wants me to further customize it so their customers feel a unique experience.

How can I respond to this request without having to change much of my application architecture? I would like to achieve this customizability just by changing a set of css files. What is the best approach for such a scenario?

Comment: CSS ==> ***Cascading*** Style Sheets

Comment: Yes, generally, do it with CSS. It really comes down to having a solid plan and naming conventions for how you use CSS, how you use classes, attributes, selectors. Look at WrapBootstrap.com (lots of other people building changeable themes there), BEM, Styled Components, for different ideas, old and new.

Comment: How about _changing a set of css files_ ? This is easily done [in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445760/how-to-change-css-href-using-javascript).